# Is this the correct way to validate data in a model?

Tags: django

I have a model that represents the normal login data and I had a question about whether it would be correct that if I verify that some data is not correct, I can return the form again but with a context that mentions the error and I don't know how to do it. I need ideas

```
class User(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=60,unique=True)
    edad = models.IntegerField()
    contraseña = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    gmail  = models.EmailField(max_length=60,unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if User.objects.filter(nombre=self.nombre):
            raise ValueError("Ya existe el usuario")
        elif self.edad >0 and self.edad <99:
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
```

Where is the else: is where the template should return again, that would be correct or maybe I should implement it another way

Comment: You don't need to manually validate it: a `ModelForm` will already check uniqness.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not correct, since the form will when validating *not* call [**`.save(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) and therefore checks in the `.save(…)` method are *not* running.

But furthermore it is not necessary. A `unique=True` field is validated by a `ModelForm`, itself. You can also add a range to your `IntegerField` with:

```
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator


class User(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    edad = models.IntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(98)]
    )
    contraseña = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    gmail = models.EmailField(max_length=60, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    # no override of .save()
```

Here we thus added [**`validators=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#validators) to the `edad` field, and these will run by the `ModelForm`s derived from the `User` model. For validators we use the [**`MinValueValidator`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/validators/#minvaluevalidator) and [**`MaxValueValidator`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/validators/#maxvaluevalidator).